# How to execute selected data flow in ssis package in runtime

Tags: ssis, execute, selected, dataflow

I have a SSIS Package, I want to execute selected data flow when I select runtime. How to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have more than one data flow in the SSIS package? Can you separate the data flows into separate packages? Or will you only ever need to run once data flow for now but may need to run other flows later manually?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers. I flagged this question for closing.

Comment: @ulrich you can't demonstrate an SSIS package without SSIS

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps.

1. Create string variable in your project.
2. On your control flow, based on your business rule, assign value to variable created in step 1 above.
3. In step 2 above, assign the short name of the data flow you want to execute
4. Create condition for checking the value of a variable under Precedence Constraint Editor for each Data flow before execution of that Data flow, if the desired value found pertaining to that DF, than a DF will gets executed or else, it won't let DF execute.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable all of the tasks and data flows that are not required. That way the remaining tasks and data flows can run alone when you execute or schedule the package to run.

Select the appropriate item right click and disable (or edit and disable)

Comment: @taner how did you get on with this? Mike